# Flat Design Definition

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I mainly work on back-end but I have a good deal of interest in UI design too. 
While going through Bootstrap 3 documentation and other tutorials, I got confused with the term "Flat Design".
What is it anyway? Can someone please explain with proper example? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Flat design is a UI design type which uses minimalistic type elements but gives a three dimensional feel and uses flat colors.
[image: Flat icon design]

what are flat colours? 
Flat colours are colours without any shading or highlighting. Just the plain colours. You can find these in the windows start menu. All the backgrounds of each application are in a single colour, no shades, no highlights, just the plain colour.

[image: Flat colors]

Answer (score 1):

I would describe "flat design" as 2D, as an opposite of 3D or "realistic design". (I'm not a designer, so I'm probably far from using the right terms)

This (graphics-heavy!) website shows the difference between them both in a funny way:
http://www.flatvsrealism.com/

**Edit 2018**

above link is no longer working, but you can find an impression here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtLz5WTxO5w

Comment: wayyy heavy, though enjoyed it. Thanks!